# "ValueError: too many values to unpack" python exception when iterating a list of list

Tags: python, debugging, exception

I was trying to build a program that manipulates functions (exercises) - shows a message about current function to activates, gets input for necessary parameters needed to activate the function, depending on the type and number of parameters, and activating it.

When trying to run it, I get the following exception:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

The code:

```
s = ['Q4', 'Q5a', 'Q5b', 'Q5c', 'Q5d', 'Q6']
f = [Trapez_rule, myFilter, myFilterMulti, myPrime, isFib, repeated]
inp = [['function', 'boundry a', 'boundry b', 'parts'], ['list', 'function'], ['list', 'list of functions'], ['number'], ['number'], ['function', 'number']]
reqtype = [['f', 'n', 'n', 'n'], ['l', 'f'], ['l', 'lf'], ['n'], ['n'], ['f', 'n']]

for j, k, l in f, inp, reqtype: # for i, j, k, l in s, f, inp, reqtype:
    # print(i)
    print(j.__doc__)
    lst = []
    for w, r in k, l:
        print(w)
        if r == 'f':
            x = input()
            x = 'lambda x: '
            exec(x)
            lst.append(x) # 'x'
        elif r == 'n':
            x = input()
            lst.append(x)
        elif r == 'l':
            m = []
            x = 0
            while x != -1:
                x = input()
                m.append(x)
            lst.append(m)
        elif r == 'lf':
            m = []
            x = 0
            while x != -1:
                x = input()
                x = 'lambda x: '
                exec(x)
                m.append(x)
            lst.append(m)
    execfunc = 'j('
    for q in range(len(lst) - 1):
        execfunc += lst[q] + ', '
    execfunc += lst[q] + ')'
    exec(execfunc)
```

I couldn't understand how to fix the code, but I think the reason is the use of nested lists as a loop's index.

Comment: I have no idea what you think `x = input(); x = 'lambda x: '; exec(x)` will do.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? Has this code ever worked?

Comment: What do you think `for j, k, l in f, inp, reqtype:` does? I don't think it does that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm pretty sure he is trying to turn user input into an anonymous function and execute it, but that's not what it does.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are confused about what this line does:

```
for j, k, l in f, inp, reqtype:
```

I believe you expect that, in the first iteration, `j` will take on the first value in `f`, `k` will take on the first value in `inp`, and `l` will take on the first value in `reqtype`. On the second iteration, each of `j`, `k`, and `l` will take on the second values of `f`, `inp`, and `reqtype`, respectively.

That isn't what it does.

Try this instead:

```
for j, k, l in zip(f, inp, reqtype):
```

Zip is described in the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/index.html) documentation, [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: It helps. But there's another issue now - the code of "execfunc" doesn't returns anything. Do you have any idea why? I tried printing the command that it will execute before, and it was fine. j points to the function. Also, the list's input while loop doesn't break when giving it "-1" as input.

Comment: I was able to solve most of the problem, besides that the functions return "None" for some reason. The call is for j with its parameters. j is the iterator for the functions list. Can you help me figuring what causes that? Also, I'm curious - was does the "zip" command actually does?

Comment: @גלזיגלר -  I won't speculate on why `j()` returns `None`. That might be worth asking in a new question. I added a link to the `zip()` doc in my answer. May I suggest that you work through [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html), and become familiar with the [standard library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/index.html)?